# Laravel Spark - selecting a plant requires new credit card info (although one has been saved/validated)

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark, laravel-cashier

Dear Laravel/spark users,

In my Laravel Spark settings page it is possible to set your payment method (and billing address). After filling in credit card info and adding it, everything appears to be stored properly. I can also charge the user via the simple $user->charge(100);
So the connection with Stripe (the payment system) is fine. However, when I go to the subscription page to select a plan, the credit card info is not used when I select a plan. I do see that the billing address is loaded but the credit card info stays empty. I have to put in the same credit card info again in order to active my subscription.

I would expect that the already stored credit card info is loaded? Is there an option that I am overlooking?

Best regards